# LAG and Partition by multiple computations

Tags: sql-server, lag, partition

I have a list of accounts and respective call reason and I did a LAG and Over Partition By. The below query told me whether the same CustomerID contacted again within 7 days and if contact more than once in 7 days returns N whilst if not returns Y.

```
SELECT 
con.[CustomerID]
,con.[ContactDate]
,con.[ContactReason1]
,ISNULL (LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]),'2999-12-31') as '2ndConDate'
,ISNULL (DATEDIFF(day,LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]), con.[ContactDate]),-1) as 'NumDays'
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]), con.[ContactDate]) < 7 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS '7DayContact'

FROM [DWH_Layer].[Layer1].[Layer2] con
```

Now I need to do a further drill down, and get if the same CustomerID contacted us in the previous 7 days using the same ContactReason1 then return N else Y.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Nested CASE to Achieve the desired result.

Comment: Can you add an example data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
con.[CustomerID]
,con.[ContactDate]
,con.[ContactReason1]
,ISNULL (LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]),'2999-12-31') as '2ndConDate'
,ISNULL (DATEDIFF(day,LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]), con.[ContactDate]),-1) as 'NumDays'
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,LAG(con.[ContactDate], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]), con.[ContactDate]) < 7 THEN 'N' ELSE CASE WHEN LAG([ContactReason1], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY con.[CustomerID] ORDER BY con.[ContactDate]) = [ContactReason1] THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END END AS '7DayContact' 

FROM [DWH_Layer].[Layer1].[Layer2] conenter code here
```

Comment: When using the Case function provided, although it works, it does not calculate the same ContactReason in the past 7 days.

Comment: Can you please help me with an example.